# Order by Case with like

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Is this a valid SQL statement

```
select title
from table
order by case when title like "%string%" then 0 else 1 end asc
```

If I use `title = "string"` I get valid results.
How can I alter this so that it accepts %string%

Comment: It is syntactically valid statement. And if `title = "string"` returns correct result - no reason to use something other

Comment: Do you want to match `%string%` literally? FYI `%` in like clause acts as a wildcard

Comment: yes I want to match with wild card

Comment: @ChasingDeath `title REGEXP "^string"` does work ! Please put it in answer

Comment: Did you try what you posted? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select title
from table
order by case when title regexp "string" then 0 else 1 end asc;
```

> > I am not putting it as **`^string`** because you were searching for **`%string%`**.

Comment: It is even worse than `title like "%string%"` while it does **exactly the same work**